# Actual OneDrive folder location

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, onedrive

I am trying to recover some files from a laptop which has unfortunately crashed and the OneDrive folder online is full. However there is some work in that folder which for Uni which I desperately need which hasn't backed up to OneDrive. This is due to the new Windows 10 Update storing the Documents on OneDrive automatically (Thanks Microsoft).

I can access the windows partition via a Ubuntu live environment, however the OneDrive folder is a symbolic link (.ink) to another area of the hard drive with no clear indication on where it would be.

Does anyone know where this folder might lie?

Comment: The folder is under Users > your_user ??

Comment: To add to what @GabrielaGarcia said, it should be at "C:\Users\\[username]\OneDrive"

Comment: Unfortunately not, that's the symbolic link (c:\users\<USER>\OneDrive.ink). It's not accessible from ubuntu

Comment: @aj.webdev - It might be on your HDD, but it isn't supposed to be a symbolic link, that is the actual location on my system.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a symbolic link, then the user has relocated his OneDrive folder.

As you are using Linux, see the post
[How do I dump information from a Windows *.lnk shortcut on Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/782135/how-do-i-dump-information-from-a-windows-lnk-shortcut-on-linux),
where the following was proposed:

> It seems there aren't a lot of programs to do this...I found two Perl
>   scripts that kinda work.
>
> **[lslnk.pl](https://pastebin.com/5uJ8ypBP)** and **[lnk-parse](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jafat/files/lnk-parse/lnk-parse-1.0/lnk-parse-1.0.tar.gz/download)**
>
> Use them like this: `<whicheverscript> Name.lnk`